# Adding and saving the rows with a for loop with Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I am trying to write a function where it modifies and places the `val1-4` in the order stated within the csv file for each iteration in the for loop and saves it. How can I use pandas to accomplish this? So the function is supposed to add rows of every time the `n` value goes up by one.

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd
FILE= 'STDOutputs.csv'
AppendFile_1Q = pd.read_csv(FILE, low_memory=False)
Values = random.randint(100, size=(100000))
Number_array = random.randint(100, size=(1000))
for n in range(len(Values)):
    val1 = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    val2 = np.sum([Number_array])
    val3 = val1 * val2
    val4 = n * 2
```

Inside of `input.csv` file:

```
val1, val2, val3, val4
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to do over here, in question description you write that you want to write data to csv and in your code you read data in pandas dataframe

Comment: I am trying to place an order val1-4 values in the csv file every time the for loop gets iterated.

Comment: then what is the use of this line `AppendFile_1Q = pd.read_csv(FILE, low_memory=False)`

Comment: to write into file you need writer not reader of csv

Answer (score 0):

You can write down your csv with the csv library. You would do something like this:

```
import csv
f = open('file.csv','w')      # Here we open the csv with "w" (write)

csv_writer_object = csv.writer(f)   # Make csv writer object

# The method writerow() writes one row of data given as list object

csv_writer_object.writerow([Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4])

f.close()                           # close file object to save data
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for, or maybe I didn´t understand very well what you wanted to do. But I think this would work. Also, we could change the *"w"* in the first line to a *"a"* if we wanted to append more info.

Comment: is there a way to not close the file and save it for each iteration since it is going through  for loop?